# What permission does my search service account need for external database searches?

Tags: search, sql-server, service-account

The farm admin for my SharePoint site has a different Default Search Service Account login than the one I am using to create my external content types (which is my personal log in). When I am trying to crawl an external database (SQL database), sometimes I get an error "BCS denied access to LOB". I checked the permissions and gave myself and the other default account permissions to both the external databases and the content source. So, is it NECESSARY for the Default Search Service Account to be the same as my own personal account or is something else the issue???

I log into the SQL database with Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your crawl or content access account.  You need to ensure it has read access to your SQL databases.

I recommend you configure a specific crawler for the DB, and specify the specific account that already has access.